# How to open pdf with HP ePrint application

Tags: android, printing, wireless

I want to try open directly PDF file with HP ePrint application, but I am little confused what parameters I should send to this package name (com.hp.android.print), so I just click print button, instead of preview using Adobe Acrobat, then I get result of my print document (more effective)

This is my code, but default open application is using Adobe Acrobat

- File dir=null;
     if (filename !=null &&  !filename.isEmpty()){
     dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Offer/"+
                                 offerordernum.substring(0,10)+"/"+filename);
     Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(dir);

  ```
              Boolean isIntentSafe=false;
              PackageManager pm = mycontext.getPackageManager();
              try {
                  pm.getPackageInfo("com.adobe.reader",0);
                  Intent intent = new Intent();
                  intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");
                  intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                  mycontext.startActivity(intent);
              }catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                  final String appPackageName = "com.adobe.reader"; // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
                  try {
                      mycontext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                  }catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                      mycontext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                  }
              }
          }else {
          }
  ```

I have already tried with changed packagename, but it was error run time. Could somebody help me to solve this problem ?
Here similar screenshot of HP ePrint document before running print

[image]